# how to set default image if image src is not found in api

Tags: javascript

hey guys what if image not found in api..how we can set default image if there is no image resouce in api..how we can handle 404 error in javascript

```js
function createNode(element) {
  return document.createElement(element);
}

var apiLink = "https://api_link_is_here";

fetch(apiLink)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    }
  })
  .then((resData) => {
      const uiDesing = resData.websites[0];
      
      uiDesing.forEach((element) => {
        // card logo
      const cardLogo = createNode("div");
      cardLogo.setAttribute("class", "card_logo");
      const img = createNode("img");
      img.src = element.logo;
      
      card.appendChild(cardLogo);
      cardLogo.appendChild(img);
          });
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Well, there is a difference between *image not found* and *no image source provided*. `img.onerror = function(){this.onerror = null; this.src = 'default.png'}`.

Answer (score 2):

### Image not found

If you do not know whether the image acutally exists (while having its source), you can use the [onerror()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) event of `img`.

```
img.onerror = function(){
    this.onerror = null;
    this.src = 'default.png'
};
```

> I would recommend to add a function in the `onerror` to actually flag the image as invalid. To remove the source and/or contact the owner. Else it keeps making unnecessary requests each time.

### Image source not provided

If you have no source or know beforehand that it is invalid, just do not assign it or assign an alternative.

```
img.src = element.logo || 'default.png';
```

### Combination

In the end, both can be combined.

```
img.src = element.logo || 'default.png';
img.onerror = function(){
    //REM: Feedback to server that this source could not be reached..
    //..
    this.onerror = null;
    this.src = 'default.png'
};
```

### Inline

Do not forget to reset the [onerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images) event.

```
<img src="404.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='default.png'">
```

Comment: @Vicky Pawar: Just combine both.

Answer (score 2):

HTML `img` tag throws console error when no image found.
So you can set onerror event when no image loaded.

```
<img src="yourImageURL" onerror="this.src=defaultimageURL">
```

Comment: Also be aware to clear the `onerror`. Since the `defaultimageURL` might not be reachable as well.

Comment: @JavaScript what do you mean?